# Using a scala extractor as a parser

Tags: scala

I keep coming across situations where I want to use extractors as parsers, they are really useful for this but it never looks right, often the unapply looks like it should be an apply. Also, the parsing extractor may get in the way of the default extractor. Are there any patterns for this?

```
case class AnID(int: Int) extends AnyVal

object AnID {
  def unapply(idString: String): Option[AnID] = "id-([0-9]+)".r match {
    case Seq(intString: String) => Try(Integer.parseInt(intString)).map(AnID.apply).toOption
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

And a test:

```
AnID(8) should be (AnID(8))
val AnID(id1) = "id-1"
id1 should be (AnID(1))
val AnID(id2) = AnID(2)
id2 should be (2)
```

It is kind of strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `Parse` object inside the companion object to make it more clear that you're parsing.

```
case class AnID(int: Int) extends AnyVal
object AnID {
  private val Reg = "id-([0-9]+)".r
  object Parse {
    def unapply(s: String): Option[AnID] = s match {
      case Reg(digits) => Some(new AnID(digits.toInt))
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

So now you at least don't clobber your normal extractor and have things that look like `val AnID.Parse(id) = "id-9"`.

Maybe that won't solve your general unease with pattern matching looking kind of backwards.  If not, you can always make Parse just implement an apply, and then you get `val Option(x) = AnID.Parse("id-9")`.

Comment: This is what I was leaning towards actually, but I needed some confirmation about it. I want to use the unapply as it allows me to match some different types of input and parse strings which are extracted from other structures. I think pattern matching is the best way to be doing this, it's just that it feels this is working against the convention